# CORS related issues in apache server

Tags: apache, rest, magento, cors, magento2

I am developing a cross platform mobile application using Magento 2 rest apis.I have enabled the **CORS** in my  apache server.

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
       # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        # Always set these headers.
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
        Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

        # Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

When i call the apis from my browser.I am getting the success response.

[image]

But in my console showing CORS related issues.

[image]

Please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` from your `000-default.conf` and also remove the `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

Those are causing multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` & `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` headers to be sent in the response. (See the **Response Headers** part in the devtools image. When browsers see multiple response headers with the same name, they merge the values of header.)

So, anyway, some other part of the server environment is already setting those headers. You either need to disable whatever else is adding those, or you just add whatever other necessary headers are not already being added.

For example, there’s only one `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the response, and only one `Access-Control-Max-Age`, so presumably your Apache config is the only thing adding those.

Comment: Removed those lines.Then i am getting a response  "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

"

Comment: Then it seems you may have accidentally introduced some other syntax error when you made the change—because simply removing those directives would not cause you to run into that error.